# Filling DataGridView ComboBox programatically in unbound mode?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

The following code snippet (The question is here: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/winforms-grids/10038-fill-datagridview-combobox-column.html) is for filling a combobox cell in a datagridview in unbound mode:

```
Dim dgvcc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
dgvcc = DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0)
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem1")
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem2")
```

I'm trying to do likewise but I can't help but notice that the casting operation is invalid and that's the exact error VB gives me.

I've tweaked the code a bit and tried it but still I get the same casting error:

```
Dim dgvcc As Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell
dgvcc = Window.DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0)
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem1")
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem2")
```

*Window* is the name of the form in which the DataGridView1 objet is.

Can anyone please show me an easy method to fill a combobox in a datagridview in unbound mode. You can as well tell me why it did not work for me and why it is working for others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the GridViewComboBoxCell, instead take GridViewComboBoxColumn and refer the code snippet given below, which will work fine

```
    Dim cbState As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    cbState = DataGridView1.Columns("cbCol1")
    cbState.Items.Add("Karnataka")
    cbState.Items.Add("Andhra Pradesh")
```

The above code will give a result like below for the DataGridview.

[image]

EDIT :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cbState As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    cbState = DataGridView1.Columns("cbCol1")
    cbState.Items.Insert(0, "Karnataka")
    cbState.Items.Add("Andhra Pradesh")

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        e.Value = "Karnataka"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey man, do you know how to set the combobox to display one of its members as default when it loads up?

Comment: Add indexing to the items, and put the default one with 0 index

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: You can use Bubbled event of DataGridView, refer the code once