# Filling a DataGridView ComboBox with values in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I'm creating a windows forms application for university. My data is stored in multible c arrays of abstract data types. Each array is displayed in it's own datagridview. This all works no problem.
Since the data is connected like in a database I added a new column to my parent table and set the ColumnType to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Now I need to fill this combobox with the data of a different array / datagridview.

I've already tried to add the options manually from my array as discribed in this question: [Filling DataGridView ComboBox programatically in unbound mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655152/filling-datagridview-combobox-programatically-in-unbound-mode). Since I need to use C/C++ and this example uses vb the used functions are not availible. I can select my column `dataGridView1->Columns[0]` but the `->Items` does not exist.

Is it possible to create a datasource from my arrays to link them directly? Or have I overlooked a way to add them manually from my array?

Comment: Oops, my mistake with the answer, sorry, I didn't noticed that your tag is c++ and not c#, neither it hit me in the text. Unfortunately, with my totally insignificant knowledge of c++ from linux and arduino, I was unable to meaningfully expand my answer and I deleted it, so that your question is indicated as unanswered. Once again, sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, it still helped me to figure out more details on my problem, though it isn't soled yet. If you can get it back it might also help others.

Comment: Well, thank you, I'm glad if it helped at least a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any code, neither you describe well where did you ran into a problem. Assuming you're after unbound list to be filled into the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, here is a simple example.

C#:

```
DataTable dt;
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add({1, "Fruits"});
dt.Rows.Add({2, "Vegetables"});
dt.Rows.Add({3, "Trees"});

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgCol = this.DataGridView1.columns("Category");
dgCol.ValueMember = "ID";
dgCol.DisplayMember = "Category";
dgCol.DataSource = dt;
```

In this example, we create a `DataTable`, fill it with desired values and use it as a `DataSource` of the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. Obviously, your **values provided to this column in the `DataGridView` `DataSource` must match IDs in the list in new `DataTable` "dt".**

You can convert an array or other data into `DataTable` or even use them directly as `DataSource`. It depends on what data you have. The principle will be very similar, though.

VB.NET:

```
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
    dt.Columns.Add("Category", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Add({1, "Fruits"})
    dt.Rows.Add({2, "Vegetables"})
    dt.Rows.Add({3, "Trees"})

    Dim dgCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = Me.DataGridView1.columns("Category")
    dgCol.ValueMember = "ID"
    dgCol.DisplayMember = "Category"
    dgCol.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: I actualy think there is no code to provide. I guess code beloging to how I fill my DataGridView doesn't really helps with my question and since I am looking for functions to solve my problem, I don't know yet what they are. If there is any you think would help I'd be thnakful to provide it.

Comment: As I discribed in my question I'm requred to use c or c++. Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem in one of these languages instead of c# or VB?

Comment: I deleted the answer due to my mistake, answering C# instead of C++. I brought it back (undeleted), because @Platte says it is still helpful.